# Using Relationships in NoSQL vs SQL

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

For starters i am new to the NoSQL concept.

I am developing essentially an API to allow users to create and store objects within our db. This will happen through a variety of front-end programs and lead to programs saving private data per user, programs sharing data, and data mining - accessing the relevant data on many users. A user can have many objects and we are not placing restrictions on what the object is or how it is accessed (programs will be responsible for ensuring communication between themselves), so likely objects will be arrays of other objects etc.

What is important is a PER OBJECT ACL for users with various permissions. I also anticipate things such as tags of objects etc.

Various lookups i can imagine are:

- direct - user asks for file
- list mine - as a user what can i see
- list owned - what objects have i created
- list tagged - what objects are tagged with 'appX' that i can access.
  and there will inevitably be many others

I include the above to show the scenario i'm considering. While at the moment i don't care so much about scalability i like the NoSQL schema free concept so that applications can query for object data i don't know about eg. /user/obj/1/2/3 where all i know is user has obj.

However the scenario seems very relational to me. User has obj, obj has permissions, permission has user and attrs etc. And i'm pretty sure i could build it in an RDMS base with just a lot of serialized objects and json data stores but it seems a prime NoSQL project (and i've heard a lot and would like to try it out).

So the questions:

- Is this a job for NoSQL?
- How do i efficiently create such links between objects (was thinking mongodb) and in general is there any documents/tutorials about how to model data in NoSQL to handle such things without excessive lookups (hopefully from an RDMS perspective). From what i've been reading i can't see a way of storing such data that can easily allow the above cases without essentially reverting to a relational system.
- Should there be a RDMS/ key-val compromise whereby core auth and privlidges are handled in RDMS giving a key off to the key/val for the object lookup (not sure how sub-object /user/obj/1/2 permission would work here). Should this ever be the answer? :)
- Any other general advice is appreciated. The touted facebook use case must answer such relationship questions so i'm sure NoSQL can do it - i'm just yet to see how it can do it better.

Thanks for sticking with a long question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOSQL**:  Massive numbers of users, speed is essential, don't really care about data integrity (its a bonus if it happens)

**SQL** (RDBMS): Everything else.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can't answer your entire question, but from my understanding:

If this is the extent of your lookups:

```
direct - user asks for file
list mine - as a user what can i see
list owned - what objects have i created
list tagged - what objects are tagged with 'appX' that i can access. and there will inevitably be many others
```

mongodb is fine. If you then need to go from file to users for any reason, then you want to use SQL.

Comment: i can see situations with things such as revoking privileges where you would have to know what users have influence on an object

Comment: @jumentous my feeling is that you should use a rdms unless you have some huge need for speed.